# SQL error when updating menu wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Recently when I tried to make changes to a menu I have in a word press website I received an error message saying

> [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE woocommerce_term_id = 110 AND meta_key = 'thumbnail_id'' at line 1]
>   SELECT * FROM WHERE woocommerce_term_id = 110 AND meta_key = 'thumbnail_id'

This is the query used

```
SELECT * FROM WHERE woocommerce_term_id = 110 AND meta_key = 'thumbnail_id'
```

For now I can still make changes to the site without any problems, but I still think that there'll be a problem when I go live with the site.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: missing table name, `FROM ??? WHERE `

Comment: @AlexK. was just about to mention that. Thats correct, you dont point to any instance of a table. Frankly im surprised the query runs at all.

Answer (score 1):

You don't supply a **table name** in your select query:

```
SELECT * FROM WHERE woocommerce_term_id = 110 AND meta_key = 'thumbnail_id'
```

Should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM <yourTableName> WHERE woocommerce_term_id = 110 AND meta_key = 'thumbnail_id'
```

SQL follows the protocol of:

```
--** pseudocode **
SELECT <tableColumns>
FROM   <table or view>
WHERE  <your conditions>
```

> For now I can still make changes to the site without any problems, but
>   I still think that there'll be a problem when I go live with the site.

Most definitely, your query will fail straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Table name is missing next to FROM, pls correctly provide the table name

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLENAME> WHERE woocommerce_term_id = 110 AND meta_key = 'thumbnail_id';
```

Please refer for basic mysql commands:

cse.unl.edu/~sscott/ShowFiles/SQL/CheatSheet/SQLCheatSheet.html